# Magento 2 - Can't add static block to my theme

Tags: magento2, php, admin, layout, blocks

I use Magento 2.2.4 and I want to add a static block with the name "support" in the right side of the top menu, but what I try not working.

I try to add this in the **phtml** file

```
<?php echo $block->getLayout()->createBlock('Magento\Cms\Block\Block')->setBlockId('support')->toHtml();?>
```

I try to add this in the **Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml**

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="support">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="support" xsi:type="string">support</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

I do something wrong?

Thank you

Comment: The code looks fine. Have you flushed cache?

Comment: the cache is off, but yes I try this too. I rebuild the static files too, nothing not work.

Comment: block is enable for sure

Comment: is not work with $this too

Comment: Is this a new theme? You might have to check your database theme table. If your theme is set to 'virtual theme' all xml changes won't work, despite wether the code is fine or not

Comment: is not in homepage, the block must be appear in the right side of the top menu

Comment: sorry I don't understand very well

Comment: Edit block in admin click on "show/hide editor" button and click "save block" and check

Comment: is the same, in the static block I add just a simple text "testing" so must be okay

Comment: inspect element in the browser, maybe your code working but CSS/JS hide your text.

Comment: I already do this I inspect the code and is not there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the below code in your **Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml** file:

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="support">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string">support</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Instead of

```
<referenceContainer name="page.top">
   <block class="Magento\Cms\Block\Block" name="support">
       <arguments>
            <argument name="support" xsi:type="string">support</argument>
       </arguments>
   </block>
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: Indeed like this is okay, thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Welcome. Happy to help!